# How to set up USB camera for Octoprint on Debian system

Tags: octoprint, usb

I installed OctoPrint on my nettop (Foxconn NT-330) to control custom-built Delta printer. I also have generic USB endoscope-type camera attached to the nettop.

Basic setup went well, printer is visible and controllable by OctoPrint server.
USB camera is visible via usb-list and mplayer can output live video.

The problem is that on the OctoPrint Webcam configuration tab it requires "Stream URL" which I don't know where to get from.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install a web-cam server on your Nettop. Octorint recommends Yawcam for windows and mjpg-streamer for linux.

mjpg-streamer: https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer
Yawcam: http://www.yawcam.com/

OctoPrint has instructions for installing mjpg-streamer on a raspberry pi. The process should be very similar for a Nettop running Debian so its a good starting place. The instructions are a little ways down the page: https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint/wiki/Setup-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-running-Raspbian

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why would I need webcam server for Windows?

Comment: I didn't notice that you said you were running debian in the title. You'll want to use the mjpg-streamer webcam server.